# Can't assign values to cv::Mat inside function

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I need to create a `Mat` object of type `CV_32FC2` to store coordinate points contained in a `KeyPoint` structure. I want to do it inside a function for clarity.

```
void myfun(vector<KeyPoint>& k){
    Mat p1_dist(1, k.size(), CV_32FC2);

    for(int i=0; i<k.size(); i++){
       p1_dist.at<double>(0, i)[0] = k1[i].pt.x;
       p1_dist.at<double>(0, i)[1] = k1[i].pt.y;
    }
}
```

The compiler underlines the "p1_dist" inside the for loop asking for a pointer to that Mat.
If I write that piece of code inside the main function the error won't happen.
Can you help me pointing out the issue?

Comment: You do realize that once you exit the function `p1_dist` will be destroyed and all what you are doing inside the loop will be for nothing right? If you want to keep the `Mat` object alive you have to pass it to your function as a pointer so that the changes that take place inside the function's body actually remain.

Comment: `p1_dist.at<double>(0, i)` should return a double reference, which cannot be accessed like an array.  You might mean `p1_dist.at<double[2]>(0, i)`.  Otherwise, I'm not following your problem with main.

Comment: You should post the exact compiler message, youd have the exact answer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to return the matrix you create. To conform to OpenCV, you can pass a reference to `Mat`:

```
void myfun(const vector<KeyPoint>& k, Mat& p1_dist){ ... }
```

Then you need to access the data values with the correct template. If you need a `CV_32FC2` matrix, i.e. a matrix of `float` with 2 channels, you need to access it with: `p1_dist.at<Vec2f>(row, col)[channel]`, i.e.:

```
p1_dist.at<Vec2f>(0, i)[0] = k[i].pt.x;
p1_dist.at<Vec2f>(0, i)[1] = k[i].pt.y;
```

It's usually clearer to use the `Mat_<Tp>` when you already know the type of the matrix. The equivalent for `CV_32FC2` would be `Mat2f`:

```
void myfun(const vector<KeyPoint>& k, Mat2f& p1_dist){  
    ...
    p1_dist(0, i)[0] = k[i].pt.x;
    p1_dist(0, i)[1] = k[i].pt.y;
    ...  
}
```

Putting all together:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void myfun(const vector<KeyPoint>& k, Mat2f& p1){
    p1 = Mat2f(1, k.size()); // Set proper size

    for(size_t i=0; i<k.size(); i++){
       p1(0, i)[0] = k[i].pt.x;
       p1(0, i)[1] = k[i].pt.y;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<KeyPoint> k = ...;
    Mat2f p1_dist;
    myfun(k, p1_dist);   

    // Use p1_dist

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, i was accessing the matrix using the wrong template.